# Maven Reference Local Idea Project As Dependency While Certain Profile Active

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I have a project that I am working on that is broken into several pieces:

- A Class Library
- A Server Application
- A Desktop Application
- An Android Tablet Application
- An Android Phone Application

Each component contains one or more Maven modules, and everything (with the exception of the class library) depends on the class library. We are doing continuous integration with Atlassian Bamboo, and builds are triggered (pushing Maven artifacts to our Nexus repo) whenever we push code to our Bitbucket repo.

Currently, if we wish to make changes to any component that requires changes to the component as well as the class library we have to make the changes to the class library, commit, push, build, deploy to nexus, and then update the pom file of the other component to get the updated library code. This can become problematic when tweaking the library code is needed, sometimes we will have to build the class library many times in a row before we have finished what we would call a feature. This results in multiple mom-snapshot releases into Maven.

What I would like to do instead is allow developers to set up a profile in Maven which, when active, would not search Maven for the contents of a library to compile against, but rather a local project. That way a developer could make a change in the source code for the class library and it would become immediately available in the IntelliJ Idea project for whichever component they are working on, while at the same time allowing our CI server to only compile against the versions of the class library which have been deployed to maven.

Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the approach we use:

- Only released versions go into our maven repo (nexus.mycompany.com)
- Developers build locally with snapshot versions until they get it right
- Test as much as possible before checking in (unit tests, integration tests)

I'll explain how we do it.

**Only released versions go into our maven repo**

In the parent pom for our project, we configure repository and snapshotRepository like so:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>mycompany-internal</id>
        <url>http://mavenrepos.mycompany.com/archiva/repository/mycompany-internal</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://mavenrepos.mycompany.com/archiva/repository/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

The goal for our continuous integration server is `clean install` (not `clean deploy`), and we use the maven plugin on our continous integration server to do releases.

Basically, only releases versions end up in our maven repo... using snapshot versions from other developers is always fraught with danger! Snapshot versions are only ever really built and used locally.

As I understand, you don't need a special maven profile to do it - this should be default behaviour. Are you able to reconfigure your environment to achieve this?

**Developers build locally with snapshot versions until they get it right**

When you say *sometimes we will have to build the class library many times in a row before we have finished what we would call a feature*, this should all occur locally - it shouldn't affect your maven repo, since you won't do a maven release until this feature is done.

If features take longer time to complete then you can work in feature branches.

When your feature is complete, commit / push the class library to source control, let it build in CI (it will be green, of course - the developer ran the tests locally first, right?), then click to do a maven release.

Now update the pom for your application project (iOS version or android version or whatever), build again locally, check in to source control, let CI build, then do a maven release.

In my experience this is pretty straight forward and shouldn't cause any workflow problems if everyone sticks to the idea that only good (tested!) code gets checked in and versions are released when needed.

**Test as much as possible before checking in (unit tests, integration tests)**

This one is self explanatory. Your application projects should contain integration tests, wherever possible, to test the interactions between your class library, your application Xyz and the framework it runs in.

More / better testing = better builds, less pain in the versioning / release process and smoother workflow.

In summary, I am suggesting to use released versions to avoid dependency conflicts and issues with snapshot versions.

The only real drawbacks are that you might find your class library goes thru dozens of versions quite quickly (e.g. 1.0.1 -> 1.0.57) but you will have full control over your build process and hopefully less of the headaches you are experiencing.

Comment: This was almost exactly what I needed. The tweak I made was specifying the version number and the dependency version numbers based upon the active profile, so on the developer machines all artifacts are 1.0-SNAPSHOT and depend on Snapshot versions of the class library modules, and the CI server will use the version numbers we specify for the other profile. Thanks!

Comment: Also, we had to run Maven in offline mode to only fetch Snapshots from the local repo.